# Perform OCR on image connected to Azure Blob Trigger

Tags: javascript, azure, ocr, azure-functions, abbyy

I'm using an Azure function to perform OCR on an image received on a Blob Trigger. I want to store the results in an output blob and I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
var abbyyclient = require('nodejs-ocr');

var client = new abbyyclient('ocrTest', 'ocrpassword', 'http://cloud.ocrsdk.com');
module.exports = function (context, inputBlob, resultBlob) {

    function ocrComplete(err, results) {
    if( !err ) {
        //context.log(results.toString());
        context.bindings.resultBlob = results;
    }
}

let apiParameters = {
    language: 'English',
    exportFormat: 'docx' 
};
client.processImage(apiParameters, inputBlob, ocrComplete);
context.done();
};
```

The code above is what I'm using in the Azure blob Trigger function but the results of the OCR returns a buffer instead of a word document though I've specified the export format. I am a complete beginner at this, can someone please help me out? Thanks.

Comment: One thing is that you should call `context.done()` from inside `ocrComplete`

Comment: Is the buffer the binary contents of a word document?  In that case, you just need to fix context.done().  That's when the blob gets written. 

The storage bindings are documented more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#output---javascript-example

Comment: Yes I got this sorted thanks. But I want to save it as a word document to the output blob. If the input image is called 1.jpg and after the OCR process it remains the same in the output blob with the name 1.jpg though it is a word document. I have to change the file extension manually to docx. Any way I can fix this?